# How to display inside html table bound checkbox list and label

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If normal table means I got output otherwise how do i get it? My aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/UserRegistration.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("[id$=txtdate]").datepicker({
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonImage: 'image/datepicker2.jpg'
        });
    });
</script>
<br />
<br />
<div align="center">
    <asp:Label ID="label2" CssClass="label" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div align="center">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="107px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<table id="Table1" align="center" border="1" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <th>
            TeamName
        </th>
        <th>
            TeamMember
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"> Team A </asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblbind" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Sinthu"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="susi"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="siva"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"> Team B </asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Text="kavya"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="subathra"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="mani"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="sunila"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div align="center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="SUBMIT" runat="server" />
</div>
<br />
<br />
```

Here I put the values directly so I can get them easily.

If team name values and team member values are in the database it means how i can bind these items using a table? If the listview gridview means using bound event, what can I use in the table and how i can get the required output?

Comment: i did that same concept in listview. but using html table means i cant .. i am the beginner... so if u know means help me...

Comment: I used html table then that table contains 2 column 1st column binding database and that team name displayed like label but the second column like team member column binding based on team name... if Team Name Having 4 names like aa,bb,cc,dd means it will be displayed check box list. i want to like this output

Comment: TeamName TeamMember
Team A 
Team B      in team member side i want to display the items in checkboxlist... its basically inside the listview gridview, repeater means easily we will get output.. but in normal html table means how we can bound????

Comment: if team name values and team member values is In database means  how i can bind this items using table.. if list view grid view means using bound event but in table What i can Use and how i can get required output?...help me..

Comment: yes correct sir...but the teammembers values based on the teamNames sir...if teamA having 3 members teamB having 2members TeamC having 4 members ,, etc,, how to i write the code for that?

Comment: please tell me how to i bind label with html table and checkbox list with label and html table?..